# Proof that $p_0, p_1,. . .,p_m$ is a basis of $P_m(F)$. Is it correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $P_m(F)$ denote the set of all polynomials with degree at most $m$ and coefficients in $F$. Where $F$ denotes the field of real or complex numbers. I was attempting to prove that a list $p_0, p_1,. . .,p_m \in P_m(F)$ such that $\deg p_j = j$ is a basis of $P_m(F)$ The following is my attempt at proving this statement.

Proof: We first show that the list $1,x,. . .,x^m$ is a basis of $P_m(F)$. Note that for all $p\in P_m(F)$, $p(x)=a_0 + a_1x +. . .+a_mx^m$ By definition of $P_m(F)$. Thus, the list $1,x,. . .,x^m$ spans $P_m(F)$. We just need to show that $1,x,. . .,x^m$ is linearly independent. To prove this, it suffices to show that for $0\le j\le m$ $x^j \not\in$ span$(1,x,. . . ,x^{j-1})$.

Suppose that $1,x,. . .,x^{j}$ is linearly dependent. Then there exist scalars not all zero such that $x^j = a_0 + a_1x +. . .+a_{j-1}x^{j-1}$. Then differentiating both sides we see that the R.H.S is non-zero and the L.H.S is zero. We get a contradiction. This shows that $1,x,. . .,x^m$ is linearly independent. Thus, is a basis of $P_m(F)$.

To show that $p_0,. . .,p_m$ is a basis of $P_m(F)$, it suffices to show that $p_0,. . .,p_m$ is linearly independent. As every linearly independent list that has the same length as a basis of a vector spaces is also a basis of that vector space. And $p_0,. . .,p_m$ has the same length as the basis $1,x,. . .x^m$. Using the same idea as before, namely that of differentiating, we can show that $p_0,. . .,p_m$ is also linearly independent. Hence, $p_0,. . .,p_m$ is a basis of $P_m(F)$.

Is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "differentiating both sides we see that the R.H.S is non-zero and the L.H.S is zero."? You would actually get $jx^{j-1} = a_1 + \ldots + (j-1)a_{j-1}x^{j-2}$, so neither side is zero. Do you mean, differentiate $j$ times?

Comment: What is your definition of $P_m(F)$?  Usually these are defined as "formal" polynomials, rather than functions, and in that case $1, x, \ldots, x^m$ are a basis almost by definition.

Comment: @JairTaylor yeah I should have been more specific. I did indeed mean after differentiating j times, we would get the contradiction. For now, a polynomial is simply defined to be a function $p : F \to F$.

Comment: I see, in that case this proof looks good (although you switched LHS and RHS.) As a matter of style, it might be good to be more explicit on the "using the same idea as before"; you could also avoid showing $1, x, \ldots, x^m$ is a basis by noting that they span $P_m(F)$ by definition and so $\dim P_m(F) \leq m+1$. Cheers